# Effective divisor in $\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$ with negative $\psi$-classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Does anybody know an effective class in $\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$ with negative $\psi$-coefficients? The standard references; Logan, Farkas or Brill-Noether divisors have all non-negative coefficients for the $\psi$-classes.

It would be much appreciated. Thanks .